# categories in a select dropdown using mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a table Products.

Products:

```
id Name         category
1  Sony Bravia  TV
2  Samsung 32   TV
3  Kenwood      Microwave
4  Sony PS3     Video Game
5  Sharp        TV
...
```

I'd like to display them in a select dropdown as

```
-- TV   --    
Sony Bravia
Samsung 32
Sharp
-- Microwave --
Kenwood
-- Video Games --
Sony PS 3
```

Is there any way I can do this in MySQL as a single query?

I'd also like to identify categories separately, so when someone selects a category rather than a product, the id in the select option somehow identifies this as a category and not a product (and when someone selects a product, it identifies it as a product). Is this possible at all?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM Products
          ORDER BY category, Name";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<select>\n";

$thisCat = NULL;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  if ($row['category'] != $thisCat) {
    echo '  <option value="category:'.htmlspecialchars($row['category']).'">--&nbsp;'.htmlspecialchars($row['category']).'&nbsp;--</option>';
    $thisCat = $row['category'];
  }
  echo '  <option value="'.$row['id'].'">&nbsp;&nbsp;'.htmlspecialchars($row['Name']).'</option>';
}

echo "</select>";
```

...although you should probably have a table of `categories` and use an FK to that table from `Products`

Comment: Thanks Dave and everyone else who helped

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can order by category.

```
  SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY category ASC
```

This puts all the products in alphabetical order by Category (the ASC is unnecessary, but I like to include it just to be verbose).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The query's simple:

```
SELECT category, Name
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY category, Name
```

The client-side code will have to implement a simple "state machine" to detect when a new category's been reached while retrieving/displaying the data.

```
$prev_cat = null;
while($row = mysql_fetch($results)) {
   if ($prev_cat <> $row['category']) {
       echo "<option>---- {$row['category']}----</option>"
       $prev_cat = $row['category'];
   }
   echo "<option>{$row['Name']}</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First adapt your sort order in the query, so the result is

```
id Name         category
1  Sony Bravia  TV
2  Samsung 32   TV
5  Sharp        TV
3  Kenwood      Microwave
4  Sony PS3     Video Game
...
```

Now do the classic group-change-dance

```
$category='__INVALID__';
while (true) {
  $row=mysql_fetch_row($query);
  if ($row) break;
  if ($row[2]!=$category) {
  echo '<option value="'.$row[2].'">---'.$row[2]."---</option>\n";
  $category=$row[2];
  echo '<option value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[1]."</option>\n";
}
```